# Laravel returns json data in different way on local and Amazon EC2

Tags: php, json, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using Laravel as back end and Angular JS for our front end REST application

Locally we are using Vagrant Homestead Environment
And we are using Amazon EC2 & RDS for our online version. We have setup Amazon EC2 using Laravel Forge

The problem we are facing is for JSON output on both the environment

Locally we are getting:

```
{"id":234,"fname":"firstname","lname":"lastname"}
```

Where 234 comes as integer
and on Amazon EC2

```
{"id":"234","fname":"firstname","lname":"lastname"}
```

where 234 comes as string

My question is what changes should be done to make the output integer for Amazon EC2?

Comment: Do both environments run the same PHP version and use MySQL?

Comment: How are you returning this object? Do you use `Response::json()` or do you just return it?

Comment: @lukasgeiter
**Homestead**
MySQL :5.6,
Laravel :4.2.11,
PHP :5.5.12

**RDS**
MySQL :5.6,
Laravel :4.2.11,
PHP :5.6.4

Comment: @Jerodev: we have used json_encode()

Comment: I suspect it is the PHP version...

Comment: You could try this option: `json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: @lukasgeiter, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK works but I will have to replace all of them now. Can you suggest something here too?

Comment: This indeed seems to be an issue with the PHP version. Is there a better solution to this? Or is this a Laravel bug? I'm getting the same issue, and I have the same problem (string on PHP 5.5, integer on 5.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the option `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` it will work:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Here are some options what you can do with your sourcecode:

#### 1. Just use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` everywhere

Not so pretty though...

#### 2. Write a wrapper function that has this option as default

```
to_json($data, $options = JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK){
    return json_encode($data, $options);
}
```

And search replace all `json_encode` with `to_json`

#### 3. Only use `->toJson` of Models and Collections

Write your own base model and base collection that implement the `toJson()` method with your desired default value:

```
public function toJson($options = JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK){
    return parent::toJson($options);
}
```

#### 4. Write your own [response macro](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#response-macros)

```
Response::macro('numjson', function($value)
{
    return Response::json($value, 200, array(), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
});
```

Usage:

```
return Response::numjson($data);
```

Comment: Thank You very much! 2 works. I made a wrapper class and replaced everything using Sublime!

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already implemented the accepted answer, but I believe the actual underlying issue is probably with the mysql driver being used on your EC2 instance.

If you're using the `php5-mysqld` driver, then integer fields in the database will be returned as strings. However, if you use the `php5-mysqlnd` driver, integer fields in the database will be returned as integers.

Homestead uses the `php5-mysqlnd` driver, so it will return integers just fine. I do not know how Forge provisioned your EC2 instance, but if it is not using the `php5-mysqlnd` driver, this would explain your issue. On your EC2 instance, run `php -i | grep mysqlnd`. If you do not have a line that reads `mysqlnd => enabled`, this is your problem.

You should be able to install the native driver with the following commands (assuming ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart
```